# Users created with PowerShell New-ADUser can't log in

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have a small problem with the New-ADUser command in powershell.
I'm trying to create a bunch of users from a file, and I can't seem to do it right.

I do create the accounts, but when I try to log into them, it tells me that the "connection method used isn't authorized" (I am sorry if the message isn't exact, the system I'm using isn't in english)

I am using a straight out of the box AD installed on a Windows Server 2012 R2. Everything was left as default for the moment.

The command I'm using is :

```
for ($i = $BeginLoopAt; $i -le $EndLoopAt; $i++) {

    $Id = $WorkSheet.cells.Item($i, 1).text
    $FirstName = $WorkSheet.cells.Item($i, 2).text
    $LastName = $WorkSheet.cells.Item($i, 3).text
    $Country = $WorkSheet.cells.Item($i, 4).text
    $Location = $WorkSheet.cells.Item($i, 5).text
    $Department = $WorkSheet.cells.Item($i, 6).text
    $AccountName = ($FirstName.Substring(0, 1) + $LastName).ToLower()

    New-ADUser -Name "$AccountName" -EmployeeID $Id -Country $County -City $Location -Department $Department -GivenName $FirstName -Surname $LastName -Path "$UserPath" -ChangePasswordAtLogon $true -Enabled $true -accountPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText "Azerty01" -Force) -passThru
```

Seeing the error, I believed that the error was coming from the fact that I didn't add a -AuthType, but after trying with both options from -AuthType, error wouldn't go away.
It event prints the following error if I choose -AuthType Basic

```
New-ADUser : The username is not provided. Specify username in ClientCredentials.
At C:\Users\Administrateur\Desktop\script.ps1:132 char:5
+                 New-ADUser -Name "$AccountName" -EmployeeID $Id -Country $County -City $Loca ...
+    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [New-ADUser], ADException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryServer:0,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.NewADUser
```

Well, Basic AuthType seems to be for SSL login, which isn't what *I want

There is close to no difference between properties of users created with Powershell and users created through GUI. (None that I have seen)
But the users created through GUI can log in, while those created by powershell can't.

What did I miss?
Thanks in advance!

**EDIT :**

After some tests, i realized that, as a matter of fact, i couldn't log in with ANY account created after the AD was installed... Kinda failed before, I thought i created a user named User3 because other names were taken, and I tested with User2 that was there before AD installation...

Meaning, I can only log in accounts that existed before AD DS was installed, and I absolutely don't know why.

Comment: I simply try to log in with one of them, in my Domain Controller (the one that was executing the script) I'm currently trying Active Directory, it's not for a production server

Comment: I just tried logging in from another VM, same problem

Comment: I believe i worded it wrong. I'm trying to log in with a domain account. Plain basic Active Directory account. When you join a machine to a domain, and log in with a domain account like DOMAIN\account

Comment: You mean you can only log into clients with local users? Did you actually join the client to the domain (and reboot afterwards)? Can you log in with a domain admin account? What does the security eventlog (on both client and DC) say about a failed login attempt?

Comment: Well, problem is solved. Someone felt like playing a trick on me and tweaked some settings so noone could login to AD except the Admin... Sorry and thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

Change the line: -ChangePasswordAtLogon $true  to -ChangePasswordAtLogon 0

Answer (score -1):

You must specify at least a SAMAccountName (using the `-SamAccountName` option) before you can login since this is the pre-windows2000 login name which is used in a lot of places in AD (it's also used in some default environment variables of users like `%username%`).

See https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617253.aspx for the documentation on `New-ADUser`.

Comment: No. The value for the `-Name` parameter populates the `sAMAccountName` attribute as well, if no explicit value for that attribute has been provided.

Comment: ok, the link to the MS document to which I referred clearly states : "
You must specify the SAMAccountName parameter to create a user." so that's where I based my solution on.

Comment: Unfortunately Microsoft's documentation can be unreliable at times.